# Why loopback-component-oauth2 include oauth2orize's source code totally?

Tags: strongloop, oauth2orize

I am testing loopback component to use it to make my product.
Currently, loopback-component-oauth2 has **oauth2orize** source code in its source directory.
As you know, **oauth2orize** is a node library that implements details of oauth2 protocol.
I think that it's enough for loopback-component-oauth2 just to do `require('oauth2orize')` to use **oauth2orize** library.
Is there any specific reason to including **oauth2orize** source code into 'loopback-component-oauth2'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We embed oauth2orize and tailor it for tight integration with LoopBack. oauth2orize doesn't have the complete extensibility we need to use it as an external module. Our changes to oauth2orize don't necessarily apply to upstream.